# Upper bound for norm of hessian by bounds of mixed directional derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$. Given upper bounds on the directional derivative for every direction $\mathbf u$, $\lVert \mathbf u \rVert = 1$
\begin{equation}
|D_{\mathbf u}f| \le C
\end{equation}
I can derive an upper bound for the gradient
by simply considering the derivative in direction of the gradient. For $\mathbf v = \frac{\nabla f}{\lVert \nabla f \rVert}$ we get:
\begin{equation}
C \ge |D_{\mathbf v}f| = |\mathbf v \cdot \nabla f| = \left| \frac{\nabla f}{\lVert \nabla f \rVert} \cdot \nabla f \right| = \frac{\lVert \nabla f \rVert^2}{\lVert \nabla f \rVert} = \lVert \nabla f \rVert.
\end{equation}

Equivalently I can write
\begin{equation}
\lVert \nabla f \rVert = \max\limits_{\lVert \mathbf u \rVert = 1} |D_{\mathbf u} f| \le C,
\end{equation}
where the maximum is achieved in the gradient direction.

---

Now for my question: Can I do a similar thing for the Hessian if I have bounds on the second directional derivatives? Given
\begin{equation}
|D_{\mathbf u}D_{\mathbf v}f| \le C_2,
\end{equation}
and knowing that
\begin{equation}
D_{\mathbf u}D_{\mathbf v}f = {\mathbf u}^T \cdot \nabla^2f \cdot {\mathbf v},
\end{equation}
does it follow that:
\begin{equation}
\lVert \nabla^2f \rVert \le C_2
\end{equation}
For this I would have to choose suitable directions ${\mathbf u}, {\mathbf v}$ such that the projection does not decrease the norm, i.e.
\begin{equation}
|{\mathbf u}^T \cdot \nabla^2f \cdot {\mathbf v}| = \lVert \nabla^2f \rVert.
\end{equation}

Comment: $\| \nabla^2 f \|$ is probably the operator norm induces by the Euclidean norm, isn't it? It is consistent, that is $\| Ax \| \le \|A\|\|x\|$. More important $\|A\| = \max_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\|$.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, yes I think the "standard" Euclidean norm. Consistency doesn't seem to help as it only leads to $C \ge \lVert uAv \rVert \le \lVert u \rVert \lVert A \rVert \lVert V \rVert = \lVert A \rVert$, as far as I can see. Do I understand you correctly that your second property would mean $\lVert A \rVert = \max_{\lVert u\rVert=1, \lVert v\rVert=1} \lVert uAv\rVert$, thus implying the statement I'm looking for?

Comment: more like $\| A \| = \max_{\|u\|=\|v\|=1} |u^T A v|$, but yes.

Comment: Then if you please formulate this a post instead of a comment, I will mark it as accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A = \nabla^2 f$ is symmetric, we can use the eigenvalue decomposition of $A$ to obtain
$$ \| A \| = \max_{\|u\| = \|v\| = 1} |u^T A v|. $$
Let $(\bar u, \bar v)$ be a maximizer. 
Then, we have
$$ \| \nabla^2 f(x) \| = |\bar u^T \nabla^2 f(x) \bar v| = | D_{\bar u} D_{\bar v} \, f(x) | \le C. $$

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on why we need an eigenvalue decomposition to arrive at the first equation? From there on everything is straightforward.

Comment: @Andre it is just a matter of convenience. there are other proofs. I am not sure whether they are significantly simpler.